# Problem with updating Compose Compiler to match Kotlin version

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I updated my compose compiler to 1.4.0 so that it works with my kotlin version(1.8.0). Problem is, I had already written my app in compose 1.2.0 . The functions do not work and when I get a prompt to download libraries, they do not download. Now I'm stuck with a half-finished app. This is my Main Activity-

```
package com.example.notetab


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Surface
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.notetab.ui.theme.NotetabTheme
import org.w3c.dom.Text
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NotetabTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
                ) {
                        topAppBar()
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
var username = "MJ"
@Composable
fun topAppBar(){
    Column() {
        TopAppBar() {
            
        }
    }    
    
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun preview() {
    Column() {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Text(text = "SemicolonSpace")
            }
        )
    }
    
}
```

Here's my gradle-

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.notetab'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notetab"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.6.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
}
```

I tried to add new imports but it didn't work. Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which libraries are you using?

Comment: I don't exactly know, but they all download from maven.

Comment: Post your build.gradle files

Comment: Which functions don't work? As I can see you have imported **org.w3c.dom.Text**, which is not compose **Text**.

Comment: That was an auto-import; functions that don't work are - Surface, fillMaxSize, MaterialTheme, Column, TopAppBar, @Preview, Text, and for some reason I am not able to mention fun topAppBar in Surface